# Do PSR standards allow both class and function to be declared in the same file?

Tags: php, function, class, standards

I want to use the following structure in my project.
File: *vendor/src/Foo/Bar.php*
Code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Foo;

function bar()
{
   // some code
}

class Bar
{
  // more code
}
```

Is such structure PSR compliant? Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the PSR documents? Is there anything in there that's confusing?

Comment: Of course. I can’t find a clear explanation of whether this is permitted or prohibited. Looks like this situation is not mentioned.That's why I posted this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: If it's not mentioned, it's not prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

Function out side class, is structured programming, I think that you can't to mixe structured programming with OOP programming. It isn't best practices! To many informations access https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Comment: Thank you for reply.
There are two nuances.
1) The function is introduced just for convenience, it redirects to the singleton's instance. For example, the CodeIgniter framework has a global functions view(), cache(), etc. There's something like that here.
2) I read the PSR standards and did not find there an unambiguous answer whether it is permissible to put a function in one file with a class.

Comment: 1 - You can create a sub folder called Helpers/Helpers.php and to put all function helpers there. You can to pull using composer vendor to autoload this one. To more information https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/
2 - It is possible but not recommended

Comment: I don't believe this is explicitly covered by the PSR standards, but it's bad practice.  If you need a "helper" function, create a seperate file for these functions.  As a matter of opinion, if you need a helper function in an object oriented application, you probably screwed up your design.  Same goes for global memory, singletons etc.

Comment: Thank you all for replies. Just one question left: do you think CodeIgniter also has screwed design because of global functions?

Comment: Yeah! CodeIgniter is a framework that work with libaries "packages open sources" like laravel "I recommend for you to learn", this packages is helpers functions development to help frameworks or private projects. You can to find many packages in: https://packagist.org